# Is there a phone/dial app could encrypt voice calls without using data network?

Tags: encryption, android, smartphone

I know there are many VoIP apps could provide end-to-end encrypted voice communications, such as Signal, Telegram..etc. But I could not find one app could do the same by using regular non-data/non-VoIP network. I found there is a [hardware-based solution](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/620001568/jackpair-safeguard-your-phone-conversation/description) on kickstart can do that. However, it is expensive and has not been updated for a while. And AFAIK, Android user also could replace their default dial app with third-party one. so there should be no technical limitation out there. Why no such app been made?

Comment: "so there should be no technical limitation out there" -- AFAIK, Android apps cannot inject audio into a phone call, except by playing it through a speaker. A custom ROM could handle what you seek, but even then, you are converting audio into an encrypted digital form, then "playing" that over the phone and reversing the process on the other side. This is akin to writing the protocol used for fax machines and dial-up modems. This would be difficult to write and may not result in very clean audio, due to the "bandwidth" limits of this type of communications.

Comment: I wrote some crude perl script which utilized openssl to accomplish this, piping aurecord raw data. But since you want an ‘app’...

Comment: Yes, that kind of apps should act as a "modem". The bandwidth should not be a problem, the "JackPair" hardware as mentioned above is using the same bandwidth, too. A custom ROM could be an accepted option, but even in the "custom ROM world", I still can not find an app could do this.